# Add calculated field in quicksight dataset

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have created a quicksight dataset containing ~10 entity ids. Each of these id's corresponds to a product name. For ease of reading, I'd like to add a calculated field to the dataset to display the product name. Ideally it would be a mapping like this:

```
entity id | product name
12345     | waterbottle 
982374    | shoes 
88393939  | speaker
```

how can I add in some sort of switch statement or if statement to create a new calculated field off these mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/switch-function.html

Here is one of the examples
switch(region_name,
"US East (N. Virginia)", "us-east-1",
"Europe (Ireland)", "eu-west-1",
"US West (N. California)", "us-west-1",
"other regions")